# function for accurate end date based on specified interval

Tags: r, dataframe, seq

I'm working on a function to create a 2-column df containing StartDate & EndDate. I'll supply 3 parameters: startdate, enddate, & interval, where interval indicates whether each row should represent different days, months or years within the range I provide.

For example, this:

```
    myfunction("2016/01/01", "2016/04/30", "months")
```

would generate the same thing as this:

```
    sd <- c("2016/01/01","2016/02/01","2016/03/01","2016/04/01")
    ed <- c("2016/01/31","2016/02/29","2016/03/31","2016/04/30")
    df <- data.frame(sd, ed)
```

And this:

```
    myfunction("2016/01/01","2016/01/05", "days")
```

would generate the same thing as this:

```
    sd <- c("2016/01/01","2016/01/02","2016/01/03","2016/01/04","2016/01/05")
    ed <- c("2016/01/01","2016/01/02","2016/01/03","2016/01/04","2016/01/05")
    df <- data.frame(sd, ed)
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    range <- function(startdate, enddate, interval){
    sd <- seq(as.Date(startdate), as.Date(enddate), interval)
    ed <- seq(as.Date(startdate), as.Date(enddate), interval) -1
    df <- data.frame(sd,ed)
    return(View(df))
    }
```

But whether I run the function for days or months, **the end date is wrong**. See:

```
    range("2016/01/01","2016/01/05","days")

    range("2016/01/01","2016/04/30","months")
```

How can I code so that my function consistently returns the correct **end** date, regardless of whether I'm looking at days, months, or years? I've reviewed other questions here but they all seem to use static intervals rather than dynamic.

Comment: Please have a look at `seq()`

Comment: Thank you, I have. But I'll need the function to go 1 day out, 30-31 days out, or 365 days out, depending.  I haven't found a way to incorporate dynamic lengths into seq() itself, or the function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)

# Start date and end date should be of character type
# interval should be "day" or "month" or "year"

get_range <- function(startdate, enddate, interval)
 {
  start <- seq(from = as.Date(start, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
                         to = as.Date(end, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
                         by = interval)
  end <- start + sapply(start, function(x){ifelse(interval == "day", 0,
                    ifelse(interval == "month", 
                           days_in_month(month(x)) - day(x),
                           365))})
  return(data.frame(start,end))
 }
```

Comment: What is the benefit to using this instead of the code I already have? Both successfully give me a list of StartDates. My trouble is getting the correct EndDates for the specified period.

Comment: The updated code should do what you need. Check it out

Comment: Thank you, but it's still giving me wonky end dates, eg. start date 2016/01/01 is showing end date of 2016/12/31, and start date of 2016/01/05 is showing end date of 2017/01/04. This is a great start, though, I'll mess with it and see if I can get it to work!

Comment: Interesting. Check the interval argument passed to the function. If it is not "day" or "month" it will give the end date assuming that the interval is a year. Just look for typos like "days" or "months".

Comment: Aha! I'd been using the syntax for seq() and thinking 'days' vs 'day' didn't matter. It works! Answer accepted with 2 changes for clarity & accuracy.